# How to Download a Single Cell Matrix File from the Web

Tags: r

I'm trying to download the single cell matrix file stored here: https://static-content.springer.com/esm/art%3A10.1038%2Fs41586-019-1362-5/MediaObjects/41586_2019_1362_MOESM3_ESM.txt
and place it into a dataframe in RStudio. I can't seem to figure out how to do that though, any suggestions? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried:

```r
download.file(url = "https://static-content.springer.com/esm/art%3A10.1038%2Fs41586-019-1362-5/MediaObjects/41586_2019_1362_MOESM3_ESM.txt",
              destfile = "Test_dw.txt")
test = read.table("Test_dw.txt", header = T, sep = "\t")
```

It works for me and I open a file with following dimensions:

```r
> dim(test)
[1] 27998 15039
```

And here the output of `colnames` and `rownames`:

```r
> head(colnames(test))
[1] "y1_AAACCTGAGTGGTAGC" "y1_AAACCTGCATATGCTG" "y1_AAACGGGAGCCGTCGT" "y1_AAACGGGAGTTTAGGA" "y1_AAACGGGCACACCGCA"
[6] "y1_AAACGGGCACGACGAA"

> head(rownames(test))
[1] "Xkr4"    "Gm1992"  "Gm37381" "Rp1"     "Rp1.1"   "Sox17"
```

Is it what you are looking for ?